# How to copy file to USB Mounted on Pi from SSH Server

Tags: python, ssh, file-sharing, file-server

I am writing a python script that checks the files in a folder on my Android, and will copy .jpg files to a USB I have mounted on my RPi.  (My Android is running as an SSH server).

I am able to connect to my Android and get a list of filenames.  I'm stuck as to how to copy the file from the Android 'server' to my USB Drive on the Pi. (Again, via Python script).

Here's what I have so far:

```
import paramiko as pmko
import os
import shutil
import subprocess


def list_files(directory, filetype, ssh):
    """
    This will scan a directory for the filetype,
    which is passed as `.jpg`, or `.mp3`, etc. and return
    a list of those files.
    """
    print("listing all photos in file.")
    distantFiles = list()
    filePath = '/storage/emulated/0/' + directory
    filePattern = '"*' + filetype + '"'
    rawcommand = 'find {path} -name {pattern}'
    command = rawcommand.format(path=filePath, pattern=filePattern)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
    for afile in filelist:
        (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
        distantFiles.append(filename)
    return distantFiles

def connect_to_phone():
    host = "192.168.0.105"
    port = 2222
    username = "logintest"
    password = "supersecretpassword"

    print("Starting connection")
    ssh = pmko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pmko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, port=port, username=username,
                password=password)
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    print("Connected!")
    return sftp, ssh


def main():
    sftp, ssh = connect_to_phone()
    files = list_files("DCIM/camera", ".jpg", ssh)
    directory = '/storage/emulated/0/' + 'DCIM/camera/'
    for file in files:
        _file = file.decode('utf-8')
        print(_file)
        #shutil.copy2(directory + _file, '/media/pi/usb/')
        sftp.put(directory+_file, '/media/pi/usb')  #no such file or directory '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/[whatever].jpg 
        quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So when I run this, I expected the `sftp.put()` to put the file in the `/media/pi/usb` folder (see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69596/4650297)), which does exist on the Pi (I followed #3 on [this site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/copy-data-raspberry-pi-pc/) to set up the USB, but named it `USB`, not `USB1` and I can't rename due to permissions error...) - see screenshot of RPI's directories [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpJUX.jpg).

However, I get this error when I run the program:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/[jpeg name].jpg'

I *think* that's because it's looking for that directory *on the RPi*, not the SSH Server.  How would I link that folder to the SSH Server, or otherwise copy the file from the SSH Server to the RPi's USB?

<sub>(I'm not sure if this is better here on RPi.SE or should be on StackExchange. Please migrate if preferable.)</sub>

Comment: `sftp.put` ... suggests sending file to the server - I thought you were trying to get files from the server ... is there an sftp.get? yeah documentation helps ... `put(localpath, remotepath, callback=None, confirm=True)` vs `get(remotepath, localpath, callback=None)`

Comment: @JaromandaX ......d'oh!! I will try that.

Comment: @JaromandaX whelp that was it. Thanks!! If you make an answer I'll mark it

Comment: @JaromandaX care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, I just needed to use the `sftp.get` method, not `.put`.